# Point to an app in windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to implement a button in my windows phone 7.1 application, that points the user to a "PRO" version of my application in windows phone store.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `click` event handler of your application, give or navigate to the URI of the pro version of your app:

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the Marketplace detail task to launch the Store or Marketplace and then display the details page for a specified app. If you do not specify the app, the details page for the calling app appears.

> MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
>
> marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier =
>   "c14e93aa-27d7-df11-a844-00237de2db9e"; // EXAMPLE
>   marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType =
>   MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
>
> marketplaceDetailTask.Show();

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx